# Difference between two Times in seconds

Tags: java

I am trying to print difference between two times in seconds in the given format. I tried all possible solutions, but unable to print below formats

```
start time: 15:15:30 
end time: 15:15:37

difference times:
    15:15:31
    15:15:32
    15:15:33
    15:15:34
    15:15:35
    15:15:36
```

Any suggestions on how can I achieve this using Java 8?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the source that generated this output? It may be more useful to debug your code since the answer is easily found in the java documentation.

Comment: How would you do it without programming? Do the same thing, but with programming. If you can figure it out on paper, you can program it.

Comment: Dunno. Maybe by writing some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the java.time library:

```
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("15:15:30");
LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("15:15:37");
for (LocalTime current = startTime; current.isBefore(endTime); current = current.plusSeconds(1)) {
    System.out.println(current);
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but that prints `15:15:30`, and example in question starts with `15:15:31`. Still, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 different `Calendar` objects and set the time as your start time and end time.

Compare these 2 instances and add a second until they both becomes equal. You can print them at the same time.

```
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance(), endTime = Calendar.getInstance();    
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

startTime.setTime(sdf.parse("15:15:30"));
startTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
endTime.setTime(sdf.parse("15:15:37"));

while(startTime.compareTo(endTime) < 0) {
    System.out.println(sdf.format(startTime.getTime()));
    startTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
}
```

**Output**

```
15:15:31
15:15:32
15:15:33
15:15:34
15:15:35
15:15:36
```

Comment: `startTime.compareTo(endTime) == -1` is not correct. [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo-java.util.Calendar-) returns 0, less than 0, or greater than 0. It is not guaranteed to return `-1` for any comparison. Besides, you don't really need two `Calendar` objects. You can just keep the end time as a `Date` object. It's a lot less overhead.

Comment: @Andreas That's true. Although I've changed my answer, but if we look at the [source for `Calendar.java`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html#2611) then we can see that it returns only 3 values, `0`, `-1` and `1`. Isn't it?

Comment: @RamanSahasi That's true, but your code shouldn't depend on undocumented implementation details.